# CMSException message-digest attribute value does not match calculated value

Tags: java, cryptography, digital-signature, bouncycastle, pfx

I am trying to sign a text using PFX in java. But the verification system(which is a centralized system and we do not have any access over it) is sending me nack messages saying signature mismatch.
Most of the part of my signature is matching with the sample provided by the verifying team.
I have no information as to what is the exact signing mechanism that they intent us to use.
I have tried all ways know to me to sign it suing PFX certificate that is common at both the ends.
I have some how got a piece of code that I am not able to understand.
I am pasting the code below. I have no idea what j,a,c etc. is.
Please help me out to understand the below code.

```
 { BouncyCastleProvider bouncyCastleProvider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
Security.addProvider((Provider)bouncyCastleProvider);
CMSSignedDataGenerator cMSSignedDataGenerator = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
PrivateKey privateKey = paramn.e();
X509Certificate x509Certificate = paramn.k();
byte[] arrayOfByte1 = (byte[])null;
DERObjectIdentifier dERObjectIdentifier1 = new DERObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.4.1.311.88.2.1");
DERObjectIdentifier dERObjectIdentifier2 = new DERObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.4.1.311.88.2.2");
DERObjectIdentifier dERObjectIdentifier3 = new DERObjectIdentifier("1.2.840.113549.1.9.5");
DERObjectIdentifier dERObjectIdentifier4 = new DERObjectIdentifier("1.2.840.113549.1.9.16.14");
AttributeTable attributeTable = null;
CMSSignedData cMSSignedData = null;
if (paramn.i() != null) {
    DERSet dERSet1 = null;
    DERSet dERSet2 = null;
    String str1 = null;
    ArrayList arrayList1 = paramn.i();
    Hashtable<Object, Object> hashtable1 = new Hashtable<Object, Object>();
    Hashtable<Object, Object> hashtable2 = new Hashtable<Object, Object>();
    Attribute attribute1 = null;
    Attribute attribute2 = null;
    Date date = null;
    DERSet dERSet3 = null;
    Attribute attribute3 = null;
    for (j j : arrayList1) {
      if (j.b())
        if (j.a().equals("1.3.6.1.4.1.311.88.2.1")) {
          dERSet1 = new DERSet((DEREncodable)new DEROctetString(j.e().getBytes()));
          attribute1 = new Attribute(dERObjectIdentifier1, (ASN1Set)dERSet1);
          hashtable1.put(attribute1.getAttrType(), attribute1);
        } else if (j.a().equals("1.3.6.1.4.1.311.88.2.2".toString())) {
          dERSet2 = new DERSet((DEREncodable)new DEROctetString(j.e().getBytes()));
          attribute2 = new Attribute(dERObjectIdentifier2, (ASN1Set)dERSet2);
          hashtable1.put(attribute2.getAttrType(), attribute2);
        } else if (j.c() == 3L && j.a().equals("1.2.840.113549.1.9.5")) {
          str1 = j.e();
          date = null;
          if (str1 != null) {
            date = new Date(Long.parseLong(str1));
          } else {
            date = new Date();
          } 
          try {
            x509Certificate.checkValidity(date);
          } catch (CertificateExpiredException certificateExpiredException) {
            a.a(a, c.a(534L), Level.ERROR);
            return 534L;
          } catch (CertificateNotYetValidException certificateNotYetValidException) {
            a.a(a, c.a(535L), Level.ERROR);
            return 535L;
          } 
          dERSet3 = new DERSet((DEREncodable)new Time(date));
          attribute3 = new Attribute(dERObjectIdentifier3, (ASN1Set)dERSet3);
          hashtable1.put(attribute3.getAttrType(), attribute3);
        } else {
          a.a(a, c.a(703L), Level.INFO);
        }  
      if (!j.b()) {
        if (j.c() == 1L && j.a().equals("1.2.840.113549.1.9.16.14")) {
          DERSet dERSet = new DERSet((DEREncodable)new DEROctetString(j.e().getBytes()));
          Attribute attribute = new Attribute(dERObjectIdentifier4, (ASN1Set)dERSet);
          hashtable2.put(dERObjectIdentifier4, attribute);
          continue;
        } 
        a.a(a, c.a(704L), Level.INFO);
      } 
    } 
    AttributeTable attributeTable1 = new AttributeTable(hashtable1);
    attributeTable = new AttributeTable(hashtable2);
    DefaultSignedAttributeTableGenerator defaultSignedAttributeTableGenerator = new DefaultSignedAttributeTableGenerator(attributeTable1);
    SimpleAttributeTableGenerator simpleAttributeTableGenerator = new SimpleAttributeTableGenerator(attributeTable);
    String str2 = b(paramn.c());
    cMSSignedDataGenerator.addSigner(privateKey, x509Certificate, str2, (CMSAttributeTableGenerator)defaultSignedAttributeTableGenerator, (CMSAttributeTableGenerator)simpleAttributeTableGenerator);
  }
```